# Can't plot values on a choropleth map

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, geopandas, folium

I am trying to convert date in my df to milliseconds by using :

```
df_covid['Date']=(df_covid['Date'].astype(int)// 10**9).astype('U10')
```

but it is showing error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13684/904624221.py in <module>
----> 1 df_covid['Date'] = (df_covid['Date'].astype(int) // 10**9).astype('U10')
      2 covid_dict = {}
      3 for i in df_covid['state_id'].unique():
      4     covid_dict[i] = {}
      5     for j in df_covid[df_covid['state_id'] == i].set_index(['state_id']).values:

TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]
```

I also tried to use `df_covid['Date']=(df_covid['Date'].values.astype(int)// 10**9).astype('U10')`
but this also did not give the desired data. I am trying to plot the covid data on map of India

Comment: given you are trying to plot covid data on a chorpleth, I don't see why you want to convert dates to integer and generate number overflow issues.  cases would be what I expect to use to drive color,  not date.  provide more details and I can find you a solution

Answer (score 0):

- looked into this in a bit more detail.

  1. Have sourced India COVID data from https://github.com/covid19india/api
  2. Have sourced India state boundaries from: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/
  3. prepared up **geopandas** dataframe to have only India states and have a joinable code for COVID data
  4. flattened and selected latest confirmed cases in **pandas** data frame
  5. used this geometry and COVID data to generate plots in **plotly** and **folium**
- found that **folium** does not like dates due to serialisation issue to JSON.  Hence dropped and used string representation
- this does not require that *date* is converted to an integer representation (as per my comment)

#### data sourcing

```
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import pandas as pd

# fmt: off
# download boundaries
url = "https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
# fmt: on

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

# load downloaded boundaries
gdf2 = gpd.read_file(str(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath(f"{f.stem}.shp")))

gdf2 = gdf2.loc[gdf2["iso_a2"].eq("IN")]
gdf2["code"] = gdf2["iso_3166_2"].apply(lambda s: s.split("-")[-1])

# get covid data by state in india
df = pd.read_csv("https://api.covid19india.org/csv/latest/state_wise_daily.csv")
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = (
    df.groupby("Status", as_index=False)
    .last()
    .loc[lambda d: d["Status"].eq("Confirmed")]
    .set_index(["Status", "Date", "Date_YMD"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_3": "State", 0: "Confirmed"})
)
```

#### plotly choropleth

```
import plotly.express as px

px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df.merge(gdf2.loc[:, ["code", "name"]], left_on="State", right_on="code"),
    geojson=gdf2.set_index("code"),
    locations="State",
    color="Confirmed",
    color_continuous_scale="reds",
    hover_data=["Date","name"],
    range_color=[df["Confirmed"].quantile(0.25), df["Confirmed"].quantile(0.9)],
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "center": {"lat": 23.5120, "lon": 80.3290},
        "zoom": 3,
    }
)
```

#### folium choropleth

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(
    location=[23.5120, 80.3290],
    tiles="cartodbpositron",
    zoom_start=4,
)

choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=gdf2.set_index("code").join(df.set_index("State")).drop(columns=["Date"]),
    name="choropleth",
    data=df,
    columns=["State", "Confirmed"],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color="Reds",
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Confirmed",
).add_to(m)

# Display Region Label
choropleth.geojson.add_child(
    folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(['name',"Confirmed","Date_YMD"], labels=False)
)

m
```